# Lambda by reference

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

I was wondering if the standard allows you to pass all members by reference using the `=`. So for instance, this works

```
int i = 0;
auto f = [&i]() {
    i = 1;  
};
```

However, this does not and neither does putting an `&` in behind of the `=`.

```
int i = 0;
auto f = [=]() {
    i = 1;  
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what you mean is:

```
int i = 0;
auto f = [&]() {
    i = 1;  
};
```

`[=]` captures everything mentioned in the lambda's body by value.

`[&]` captures everything mentioned in the lambda's body by reference.

Answer (score 1):

In this lambda expression

```
int i = 0;
auto f = [=]() {
    i = 1;  
};
```

captured variable i that is a data member of the lambda is changed within lambda. So you have to write

```
int i = 0;
auto f = [=]() mutable {
    i = 1;  
};
```

If you want that the i would be captured by reference you should write

```
int i = 0;
auto f = [=,&i]() {
    i = 1;  
};
```